# no-unsafe-optional-chaining rule does not work on property object

Tags: eslint

```js
    const b: {
        a: number, c?: {value: string}
    } = {a: 111, c: undefined}
    b.xxx
    b.c.value
```

The eslint rule no-unsafe-optional-chaining works ok on the line `b.xxx`, but I think the `b.c.value` should also been marked error.
[image]